# Can't create IBOutlet for UIBarButtonItem in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I'm trying to create an IBoutlet from a UIBarButtonItem to a UIViewController, but when ctrl+clicking and dragging to the controller, I see no indicator whatsoever, and thus it's impossible to create it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the screenshot, in case it could clear something up:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I also tried to create the IBOutlet manually with `@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem;` and then ctrl+clicking and dragging, but same result.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to create a UIBarButtonItem IBOutlet

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cameraLibraryToggleButton;
```

[image: Storyboard showing view controller's outlets]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can create an IBOutlet for a `UIBarButtonItem`... Instead create a IBOutlet for your `UIToolbar` and give your `UIBarButtonItem` a tag of 1. Next use this code:

```
 for(UIBarButtonItem *button in self.toolBar.items)
 {
       if(button.tag == 1)
       {
            UIBarButtonItem *newButton = button; //Your UIBarButton   
            //Do whatever you want with it.
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if u used story board then select UIBarButtonItem item and just put on the view controller.then, set IBOutlet. try this

Comment: in view controller first put Navigation bar.Means hierarchy is first view, second scroll view then navigation bar and then put bar button item. set your hierarchy.

Comment: in your hierarchy into navigation bar are below.and also broke first all connection then reset your connection.

Comment: @RenishDadhaniya it doesn't work. I even try to create the outlet in the left bar of the Storyboard, where you see the hierarchies, from UIBarButtonItem to UIViewController and what I see is the little popup to create a Segue.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have assign class (e.g .UIViewController) to your storyBoard

Comment: how can you check that (specifically)